# Bing Custom Search API results

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, bing-api, bing-search

I have  2 queries  with regards to the definition of web slices that I wish to configure for my custom search instance. I want my search results to  be retrieved from  any URL that has the following  pattern:

http://domain-name/*

Ideally I want to have my search results to include all that is in this domain and within any resources that has this URL pattern.

How do I configure the same?

Secondly, I am  observing that my search results  including URL pattern www3.domain-name when I have not included this at all in the custom instance.

Configured:

a) domain-name.com

b) https://www.domain-name.com

What  I see in the results:

results from www3.domain-name.com

Why does this happen.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls include subpages (say "Yes" for "Include subpages?") for including all pages under the domain. For incidents such as www3.domain-name.com, you can block from the "blocked" tab in Definition Editor.

Comment: Yes. I have enabled "YES" for the subpages to be included from the specified domains.  Blocking the  results from www3.domain-name.com would definitely help but I am curious as to understand why they get included in the search results when they are nowhere specified in the listed domains.

Comment: Can you pls provide a snapshot of how this is configured in your instance? You don't need to put * for example in your instance. Regarding www3 results surfacing, my hunch is because you are including domain-name.com without any prefixes. Just a hunch though.

Comment: What prefix is required. Can you please help understanding this part?

Comment: I was talking about missing **www** in domain-name.com

Comment: removing simply the domain-name.com  configuration worked.

Comment: Does Bing Custom Search allows sorting of results based on relevance or date?